# How to find dates in any text with regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, expression

I have a text extracted from an OCR program. I manage so far to get every element I wanted except the date. My date would be like this in some cases `ASDICA>31.04.2019END($>` and in others will be with spaces (which are easy to extract). My question:
Is there any quick function without nested `for` loops to parse through the text and extract dates?

My first amateur thought was to build a list with the common date separators, parse the text, save the position of the elements found in the text and then search their relatives to build a date.

This took a lot of time and proved troublesome because I'm hitting many escape chars due to OCR's behavior.

My ideal output would be `31/04/2019` but I can handle the symbol replacement as long as I got a list with the dates from the text.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}(?!\d)', string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with `SDICA>31.04.2019END($>` is not a valid date :) April just has 30 days in a month.

But to answer your question, you can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module, especially the [parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) function for the problem at hand

```
from dateutil import parser

#Parse date from the string, fuzzy parameter can find hidden datetime string around a wall of text
print(parser.parse('ASDICA>31.01.2019END($>', fuzzy=True))
```

The output will be `2019-01-31 00:00:00`

Comment: Yeah, I was giving an example... It doesn't work, it only finds the dates with whitespaces I've already got. The encoding is `utf-8`.
`('Unknown string format:', 'ΕΙΔΟΣΠΑΡΑΣΤΑΤΙΚΟΥ:Τιμολόγιο(ΠώλησηΑγαθών)ΣΕΙΡΑ:Ε3ΑΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ:0521667ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ:02.04.2019ΚΩΔ.ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗΕΙΔΟΥΣΠΟΣΟΤ.` in this example the date is `02.04.2019`. If I search for it directly for example. `if '02.04.2019' in str():` It will appear. I want to say `if `dd.mm.yyyy' in str()`

Comment: What language is this? I never dealt with non utf-8 characters being used in `parser.parse` @Magotte

Comment: Greek, I found the solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh +1 for pointing out that April has only 30 days :D

Comment: Nice, so you can encode and decode this string with the correct charset and it should work! Anyways if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it :) @Magotte  Let me also try to convert this string so that we can parse out date from it without using regex

Comment: The answer came from Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: No problem, I said if the answer `helped` you in any way, which in a way it did, since you did not specify `Greek` in the original question, so in the scope of the question you posted, my answer will work, hence I politely asked you to accept the answer @Magotte :)

Comment: It didn't actually sorry. But it can help others I guess

Comment: Cool, thanks for the accept @Magotte Have a good day :)